# Does an iframe embeded webcam contribute to a websites bandwidth

Tags: iframe, webcam, bandwidth

We are wanting to embed a live webcam on our website. It is successfully working using an iframe linked to the webcams IP address/port. The website hosting doesn't have unlimited bandwidth. Will this add to the websites bandwidth or does it bypass the web server and stream straight to the browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test hosting account that monitors bandwidth. I added the webcam iFrame and let it run for a couple of hours. I checked the bandwidth meter and there wasn't any significant bandwidth used. From this I am assuming the video bypasses the web hosting server and goes straight to the browser. :)